# Erros ao definir as bordas de uma matriz N x N? IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, array, matriz

Criei uma função que recebe como parâmetro uma matriz NxN, e imprime a principio a borda superior da matriz, porém fico recebendo o erro "IndexError: list index out of range", e isso impede que chame outras funções.

```
def bordaSuperior(matriz): # Separa os números da borda superior
lin = 0
col = 0
for i in matriz: # Valores da Borda Superior
    for j in matriz:
        print(matriz[lin][col])
        col += 1
```

Comment: Sua lógica está errada... Você incrementa apenas a variável `col`, ou seja, se você tiver uma matriz 3x3 você tentará acessar `matriz[0][0]` até `matriz[0][8]`. E como você pode perceber não existe este elemento nas listas..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está na lógica da sua função. Primeiro de tudo, você não reinicia a variável `col` depois de ter percorrido a linha. A consequência disso, é que a variável será incrementada até um ponto em que seu valor se torna maior que o tamanho da sua linha, gerando um `IndexError`.

Segundo, você percorre em dois laços `for` a matriz e não as linhas dela. Isso significa que `col` pode ter um índice maior que o tamanho da sua linha gerando novamente um `IndexError` ou o laço `for` pode não percorrer todos os valores da linha porque o tamanho da matriz pode ser menor que o tamanho da linha. Veja abaixo o código corrigido:

```
def bordaSuperior(matriz): 

    lin = 0

    for y in matriz:

        col = 0

        for x in y:

            print(matriz[lin][col])
            col += 1

        # lin += 1 se deseja imprimir todas as linhas e não só a primeira
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui entender o erro. Agora parece óbvio, vlw!